# WMI reports non-unique processor id, hard drive id and mac address

Tags: c#, wmi

We have the following code to retrive the harddrive id processor id and mac address:

```
    private static string GetWMIValue(string query, string propertyName)
{
  try
  {
    using (ManagementObjectSearcher search = new ManagementObjectSearcher(query))
    {
      using (ManagementObjectCollection results = search.Get())
      {
        foreach (var result in results)
        {
          if (result != null && result[propertyName] != null)
          {
            return result[propertyName].ToString();
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  catch
  {
    // do nothing.
  }

  return null;
}

public static string GetHardDriveSerialNumber()
{
  string driveLetterName = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location.Substring(0, 1);
  return GetWMIValue("SELECT VolumeSerialNumber FROM Win32_LogicalDisk WHERE DeviceID=\"" + driveLetterName + ":\"", "VolumeSerialNumber");
}

public static string GetProcessorId()
{
  return GetWMIValue("SELECT ProcessorId FROM Win32_Processor", "ProcessorId");
}

public static string GetMacAddress()
{
  return GetWMIValue("SELECT MacAddress FROM Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration WHERE IPEnabled = TRUE", "MacAddress");
}
```

This works fine EXCEPT on one particular brand of tablet (as far as we know).  On this brand, every machine has the same 3 values.  As you can imagine, this screws with our licensing somewhat.

Has anyone ever seen this or does anyone have a better more reliable mechanism?

Thanks

Comment: Try adding to your formula the `SerialNumber` and `Signature` values of the [Win32_DiskDrive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394132%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) WMI class.

Answer (score 0):

After a bit more research it appears as though this is a well know and talked about issue.  I need to do some work...

Thankfully, this wasn't my mess :)  I just have to fix it :(